# How to download jpeg image for browsers in Delphi / C++ Builder REST WebBroker?

Tags: rest, delphi, c++builder, mime, delphi-xe7

I have to develop a REST method to return jpeg files for browser in RAD Studio XE7.
Calling the method, the browser tells the image can not be showed because it contains errors; I don't understand why.

Here is the code of method:

```
void TCommerMethods::DownloadImage()
{
UnicodeString Ret;
TMemoryStream *Stream;
TIdEncoderMIME *MIMEEncoder;

  Stream = new TMemoryStream;
  Stream->LoadFromFile("C:\\Temp\\MyImage.jpg");
  Stream->Position = 0;

  MIMEEncoder = new TIdEncoderMIME(NULL);
  Ret = MIMEEncoder->EncodeStream(Stream, Stream->Size);
  delete Stream;
  delete MIMEEncoder;

  GetInvocationMetadata()->ResponseContentType = "image/jpeg";
  GetInvocationMetadata()->ResponseContent = Ret;
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do not MIME encode the image file. The server should write the JPG resource to the HTTP response unmodified.

Try this:

```
void TCommerMethods::DownloadImage()
{
  TStringStream *Stream;
  String S;
  Stream = new TStringStream;
  Stream->LoadFromFile("C:\\Temp\\MyImage.jpg");
  S = Stream->DataString;
  delete Stream;
  GetInvocationMetadata()->ResponseContentType = "image/jpeg";
  GetInvocationMetadata()->ResponseContent = S;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion helps to find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mjn I solved the problem. The following code works fine. Hope it may be useful to others:

```
void TCommerMethods::DownloadImage()
{
TStringStream *Stream;
String S;
  Stream = new TStringStream;
  Stream->LoadFromFile("C:\\Temp\\MyImage.jpg");
  S = Stream->DataString;
  delete Stream;
  GetInvocationMetadata()->ResponseContentType = "image/jpeg";
  GetInvocationMetadata()->ResponseContent = S;
}
```

Comment: note that on Stack Overflow, you can honor an answer by accepting it